# How to use javascript to add classes to text and image

Tags: javascript

I would really appreciate help with running a query for .parentContainer, then find text ABC123 and wrap this in a div with ID="abc123". I already have some simple code that will add content to the new div element.

Further to that, is it possible to also query .parentContainer for the presence of ABC123, and then add a new class to the image if ABC123 exists?

Sorry if I appear a bit lazy here. I have really only started dabbling with JavaScript and have been reading lots on manipulation of the DOM. I tend to learn loads from studying and tweaking code that can apply to my own real scenarios.

Thanks so much!

```js
let parentContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.parentContainer')
  for(let [i,f] of parentContainers.entries()){
    if(f.innerText.includes('ABC123')){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = 'ABC123';
    div.setAttribute("id", "abc123");
    f.append(div)
  }
}
```

```css
#ABC123 {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#abc123 {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.abc123 {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
.parentContainer {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <a class="productImage" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/product-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Product 1 Image"></a>
  <div class="productInfo">  
ABC123
Product summary description goes here.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parentContainer">
  <a class="productImage" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/product-1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Product 1 Image"></a>
  <div class="productInfo">  
ABC123
Product summary description goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
let parentContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.parentContainer')
  for(let [i,f] of parentContainers.entries()){
    if(f.innerText.includes('ABC123')){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = 'ABC123';
    div.setAttribute("id", "abc123");
    f.append(div)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the snippet. It looks like a new ABC123 text string has been added/appended after the original text, and this has been given the #abc123 ID. I need the original ABC123 text to be given the ID #abc123, and the image given a class (any class will do). It would also be possible to add the image class by selecting .parentContainer according to ABC123 text being present, then add class to .parentContainer > img.  Thanks again - hope you can help further.

Comment: you can manipulate it using selector.classlist.add('classname') OR .toggle('classname')